# Ubuntu 19.04 Bluetooth not working correct. "Not Set Up" button always disabled

Tags: bluetooth, 19.04

Since some days I have the problem that my bluetooth is not working anymore. The bluetooth settings dialog shows me the following.

[Not Setup disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhMHf.png)

The devices image is rotating all the time and I can't press anything. 
It's a 2 weeks old total fresh ubuntu 19.04 installation. With 18.10 this was working without any issue.

Here is my output of

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
```

Output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1043:86cd]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:2142]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1825 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Qualcomm Bluetooth 4.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    2.660272] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.660278] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.660280] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.660281] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.660282] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.867907] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.867908] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.867909] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.915809] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.915813] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.915816] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  521.274925] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000c16f8c2c failed to resubmit (2)
```

Did somebody has an idea what turned my bluetooth into that issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Thx .. Done.. :-)